# Lots of functions vs Lots of Lambdas?

Tags: lambda, delegates, c++11, header-files, anonymous-function

I've posted a few questions prior to this one regarding the use of `std::function` over fast delegates, and ways in which one can store `std::function` in a collection to exhibit the behavior of an event that can be added and removed to.  I also enquired as to best-practice when writing a whole ton of little `EventArg`-type classes, and that little design decision has also been put to rest.  This is a great community!

Now, preamble aside, I have must of my structure in place and it is time to write all the handlers that will deal with incoming data.  I have a `std::map`, that looks like this:

```
typedef std::function<void(const CommandData&)> CommandDelegate;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<CommandDelegate> CommandDelegatePtr;
typedef std::map<short, CommandDelegatePtr> CommandMap;
```

And I wish to add about 200 handlers to this.  I have the choice between standard member functions, and lambdas.

The first thing I thought about, when thinking about member functions, was 200 declarations and 200 implementations and one big-ass source file.

Rather than pollute my class with all these handlers I thought "Well, they're just handles, why not use lambdas?  It seems simple enough, when the class is constructed it can assign all these anonymous functions to the map.  Job done!

Then I realized the constructor would be huge.  I could call a 'initializeMap` helper function that could conceivably go in it's own file due to the size.

What do you guys think?

1. 200 declarations in the `.h` file, 200 implementations (amongst other functions) in the .cpp file
2. 200 declarations in the `.h` file, a separate 'handlers.cpp` implementation file
3. No declarations, 200 lambdas assigned in the ctor
4. No declarations, 200 lambdas assigned in an `initializeMap` function in it's own file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is, use lambdas wherever possible. They're much more maintainable. For example, if you have a member function, you will have to update the declaration and definition every time you change it, and you will also have to assign it a unique name. Lambdas are the superior option. If I could have automatic type deduction on member variables, I wouldn't ever use member functions.

Comment: I am kind of leaning towards the lambdas.  I love the idea that my main class won't have a crapload of small handlers.  So I guess the question is, assigning them - hence the question about the class constructor/initializer function.

Comment: 3 or 4, it really doesn't matter, although my personal preference is more source files rather than less, as modern compilers can compile concurrently.

Comment: I pretty much agree, but wanted to make sure.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need those functions to be dynamic? Because if your only concern is to not pollute your main class, there are better (faster) solutions, like making a subclass, or just dividing all the code into multiple files.

If you have your header with the 200 functions, but in never changes, it won't bloat your project so much, because it will just lie there. A bloated constructor on the other hand is worse, because there is a higher chance that you will have to change it sometime, and then it will have to recompile all those 200 initialisations.

That compile time probably won't be that long anyways, but why bother at all?

I would just keep them functions with declarations, either in your main class, or in some other dedicated class or file, but not initalising them dynamically in ctor.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by 'dynamic'...  data is coming in with a code and the appropriate handler for that code has to be called, hence the map with a `std::function`.  If this is not what you meant by dynamic, what did you mean?